# Dividing column value based on concurrent date ranges in another table?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with day level recordings (guaranteed consistent interval between rows), and another with events data (event_id, when the event started and ended).

Multiple events can happen at the same time, and sometimes- no events at all.

If an event is ongoing, I want to assign `df$y` to it, and if multiple events are happening at the same time, divide `df$y` by the number of ongoing events and assign it equally. If an event is over or is not taking place, I want it to read 0.

I want to add these divisions as columns to the day level recording dataframe, and have columns that correspond to something like-

`date, y, event_1, event_2, event_3`

```
#Time series observations
df = data.frame('date' = c(seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-05-01'), 'day')))
df$y = runif(nrow(df))

df

          date          y
1   2019-01-01 0.71633962
2   2019-01-02 0.18424328
3   2019-01-03 0.69779743
...
```

```
#Events observations
df_date = data.frame(
  'event_id'= c(1,2,3),
  'start'= c(as.Date('2018-12-04'), as.Date('2019-01-02'), as.Date('2019-04-15')),
  'end'= c(as.Date('2019-03-02'), as.Date('2019-01-20'), as.Date('2019-05-15'))
)

df_date

  event_id      start        end
1        1 2018-12-04 2019-03-02
2        2 2019-01-02 2019-01-20
3        3 2019-04-15 2019-05-15
```

Comment: I think this is a nice question, but you should give an example that allows all your requirement to be tested (here you don't have a date with several events), and give the desired output, so the people can check if they correctly answered.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll do that and update it; till then, events 1 and 2 have overlapping dates- as such, only half of y should be assigned to each event. If there was another event that overlapped 1 and 2 (total of 3 events), only 1/3rd of y should be assigned to each event.

Comment: my fault, I didn't correctly read. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, a `base R` approach should be,

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_date)) {

     df[,i+2]<- ifelse((df_date$start[i]<=df$date &  
     df_date$end[i]>=df$date),df$y,0) 

     colnames(df)[i+2] <- paste0("event_",i)    

}



df[,3:5] <- (df[,3:5]!=0) * ifelse(rowSums(df[,3:5]!=0)==0,0, df$y/rowSums(df[,3:5]!=0))

head(df)

      date         y      event_1  event_2    event_3
 1 2019-01-01 0.2655087 0.2655087 0.0000000       0
 2 2019-01-02 0.3721239 0.1860619 0.1860619       0
 3 2019-01-03 0.5728534 0.2864267 0.2864267       0
 4 2019-01-04 0.9082078 0.4541039 0.4541039       0
 5 2019-01-05 0.2016819 0.1008410 0.1008410       0
 6 2019-01-06 0.8983897 0.4491948 0.4491948       0
```

Comment: Almost there! If any 2 or more events are happening at the same time, I want to divide y by the number of ongoing events and assign `(y/#_events)` equally to each ongoing event.

Comment: I added the code :  `df[,3:5] <- (df[,3:5]!=0) * ifelse(rowSums(df[,3:5]!=0)==0,0, df$y/rowSums(df[,3:5]!=0))` . I think it is what you want with using base R. Of course, you can use `df[,3:nrow(df_date)] ` instead of `df[,3:5]` if you have more than 3 events.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df_date)

dcast(
    df_date[df, on=.(start<=date, end>=date)][, y := y / .N, start],
    start ~ event_id, , value.var="y", fill=0)
```

output:

```
          start NA   1   2   3
  1: 2019-01-01  0 1.0 0.0   0
  2: 2019-01-02  0 1.0 1.0   0
  3: 2019-01-03  0 1.5 1.5   0
  4: 2019-01-04  0 2.0 2.0   0
  5: 2019-01-05  0 2.5 2.5   0
 ---                          
117: 2019-04-27  0 0.0 0.0 117
118: 2019-04-28  0 0.0 0.0 118
119: 2019-04-29  0 0.0 0.0 119
120: 2019-04-30  0 0.0 0.0 120
121: 2019-05-01  0 0.0 0.0 121
```

data:

```
df = data.frame('date' = c(seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-05-01'), 'day')))
df$y = as.numeric(1:nrow(df))

df_date = data.frame(
    'event_id'= c(1,2,3),
    'start'= c(as.Date('2018-12-04'), as.Date('2019-01-02'), as.Date('2019-04-15')),
    'end'= c(as.Date('2019-03-02'), as.Date('2019-01-20'), as.Date('2019-05-15'))
)
```